# SharePoint 2010 QueryManager GetResults always returns null

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

We're trying to implement custom search for a project but I can't get the QueryManager to return results, where the default SP 2010 search *does* get results for the same query.

Here's the code of the search implementation (based on this: [How to: Use the QueryManager class to query SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Search](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/08/15/how-to-use-the-querymanager-class-to-query-sharepoint-2010-enterprise-search.aspx)):

```
public static void RetrieveSearchResults(string query)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {

            //// get the query and settings service proxy
            //SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue<SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy>();

            //// get the search service application proxy by name
            //SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue<SearchServiceApplicationProxy>("Search Service Application");

            var site = SPContext.Current.Site;

            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);

            SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = serviceContext.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;


            // create QueryManager and LocationList objects
            QueryManager queryManager = new QueryManager();
            LocationList locationList = new LocationList();

            // add the federated location we want
            Location localSearchLocation = new Location("LocalSearchIndex", searchProxy);

            // set the start page and page size
            localSearchLocation.ItemsPerPage = 5;
            localSearchLocation.StartItem = 1;

            // add our managed properties

            localSearchLocation.RequestedProperties = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()
            { 
              "Title", "Id"
            };

            // add the Location to the LocationList
            locationList.Add(localSearchLocation);

            // set the query
            queryManager.UserQuery = query;
            queryManager.Add(locationList);
            queryManager.IsTriggered(locationList);

            // make the call to search
            XmlDocument xmlDocument;
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
            {
                xmlDocument = queryManager.GetResults(locationList);
            });


            // write out the results
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText("results.xml", xmlDocument.InnerXml);

            //Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.InnerXml);

            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

(I've added the run with elevated privileges to check whether that makes a difference.)

Now, I don't understand why the result is always null. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it doesn't throw an exception, but the Location object has a property named 'Exception'. After the query executed it had the following exception:

*"Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings"*

So I removed this part of the code:

```
            localSearchLocation.RequestedProperties = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()
            { 
              "Title", "Id"
            };
```

And now it *does* return results. Every property should be a managed metadata property.